# How to get VS/MSBuild to Warn when calling async void in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, async-await

How can I get Visual Studio / MSBuild to warn when calling an async void function ?

We have had a few bugs where we have accidentally called an async void event handler instead of awaiting the async Task (similar names).

I would like VS to warn whenever someone does this.

CS4014 is fired if you call an async Task without awaiting it. I would like the same behaviour.

Eg

```
async void DoStuffHandler()
{
    await DoStuff();
}

async Task DoStuff()
{

}

async Task DoMoreStuff()
{
    //Warn that we probably called this by mistake
    DoStuffHandler();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can't find a Code Analysis approach, and depending on where you are using this, a novel approach might be to use some attributes and setting it `private` (which it should be already I guess):

```
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
```

[EditorBrowsableAttribute Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.editorbrowsableattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Hide a property of a class
> from IntelliSense by setting the appropriate value for the
> EditorBrowsableAttribute attribute..

and [ObsoleteAttribute Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.obsoleteattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
[ObsoleteAttribute("OMG DONT USE THIS")]
```

Comment: This would rely on me remembering to add the attribute. Being as most event handlers are auto generated when I use resharper they would almost certainly be forgotten as well.

Comment: @rolls then you are going down the path of a vs plugin, or some sort of code analysis